# VSPackage register a method when document is saved

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to register a method when a document is saved.

I tried to use DocumentEvents.DocumentSaved but this event is fired even if the save has made nothing, I mean the document was already saved when the the save commmand was executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Running Document Table provides a call back for before save in `IVsRunningDocTableEvents3::OnBeforeSave`

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdoctableevents3.onbeforesave.aspx

You need to create an implementation of `IVsRunningDocTableEvents3` and call the `AdviseRunningEventsMethod` with your implementation

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdocumenttable.adviserunningdoctableevents.aspx

Comment: @Samuel_xL no, it's still very much alive. I use it only as a last resort though

Comment: how does this differ from the DTE solution. They are both called even if the document is has no changes done since last save.

Comment: @Doggynub hmm, I assumed that the RDT solution was only called when an actual save occured.  You may need to peek at the dirty bit on the document to see if its actually dirty on save

Comment: the thing is I can check the bit but the thing I need to do must be done after the save has occured, and I cant check the dirty bit in the `onAfterSave` method because it will always be false.

Comment: @Doggynub why not set a flag in OnBeforeSave if it is dirty and then in OnAfterSave if the flag is set execute the code?

Comment: what if the active document changed? and that one was already saved.

Comment: @Doggynub don't assume the active document is the one being saved, it very often isn't.  Instead you should be going off of the `docCookie` value that is passed into `OnBeforeSave / OnAfterSave`

Comment: my fault, I even think that document cant change between these 2 calls anyway.

Comment: @Doggynub it can absolutely do so which is why the flag you set should include both the "was it dirty" and "what was the docCookie".  That way when you get OnAfterSave you check check that the docCookie matches and that it was dirty when OnBeforeSave was called

Comment: sorry to reask, but I cant find a way to query if the document is not saved. I have tried get document info and checking the flags but nothing works. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the save command :

```cs
class Foo
{
    DTE dte;
    CommandEvents commandEvents;

    // ...

        this.commandEvents = this.dte.Events.CommandEvents;
        this.commandEvents.BeforeExecute += new _dispCommandEvents_BeforeExecuteEventHandler(CommandEvents_BeforeExecute);

    // ...

    void CommandEvents_BeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        if (ID == 331)
        {
            // "Save" invoked
        }
        if (ID == 224)
        {
            // "Save all" invoked
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this is what I have done but I used the GUID and ID in the CommandsEvent[GUID,ID] but the thing is I want to know that after it is saved not before. I have used some boolean variables to accomplish that in The DocumentSaved event but I was wondering if there is a better direct way.

Comment: Well, use AfterExecute instead of BeforeExecute ?

Comment: Yes how to check if this save did an actual save. I used this in before by getting the `ActiveCocument` and checking the `Saved` property

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want to listen to actual saves, the DocumentSaved event should be enough. On the other hand, if you want to listen to the save command even if the document is already saved, then the BeforeExecute/AfterExecute should be enough. What did I miss ?

Comment: You know the file have not changed since the last save performed, then I execute another save, though the document have not changed, so this save did nothing. I only want to call a method when the save is executed and the file has some changes that needed to be saved.

Comment: and can I ask you how you got the ID of the command? because I spent a while to get the save command ID.

Comment: Sorry but I can't make sense of what you're trying to explain. About the ID : I just log every ID to the output window with System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write whenever I need the id of a command.